# fwrite incorrect value assignment writing matrixes in a binary file

Tags: c, matrix, fwrite

I am trying to make a program that writes matrixes in a binary file. The 1st two items are the rows and columns of the matrix, and then the rest of the values. 
The data of matrix are floats (when it was all in ints, it worked, but when I changed the values to floats it stopped working).

The next piece of code is the method to write the matrix in a binary file. It is the part where everything crashes. 
The Matrix definition is the next one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Matriz_t {
    int numFilas;
    int numColumnas;    
    float** datos;
}Matriz_t;
//create matrix
Matriz_t* crearMatriz(int numFilas, int numColumnas)
{

    Matriz_t* nMatriz = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    nMatriz = (Matriz_t*)malloc(sizeof(Matriz_t));
    nMatriz->numColumnas = numColumnas;
    nMatriz->numFilas = numFilas;

    nMatriz->datos = (float**)malloc(sizeof(float*)*numFilas);
    for (i = 0; i < numColumnas; i++) {
        nMatriz->datos[i] = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*numColumnas);
    }
    return nMatriz;
}
//read matrix
void leerMatriz(char * nomFichero, Matriz_t ** m1, int traspuesta)
{
    FILE* f1 = NULL;
    int i, j;
    int numFilas = 0, numColumnas = 0;

    f1 = fopen(nomFichero, "r");


    fread(&(numFilas), sizeof(int), 1, f1); . 
    fread(&(numColumnas), sizeof(int), 1, f1);
    (*m1) = crearMatriz(numFilas, numColumnas);
    if (traspuesta) {

        for (i = 0; i < (*m1)->numFilas; i++)
            for (j = 0; j<(*m1)->numColumnas; j++)
                fread(&((*m1)->datos[j][i]), sizeof(float), 1, f1);

    }
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < (*m1)->numFilas; i++)
            fread((*m1)->datos[i], sizeof(float), (*m1)->numColumnas, f1);
    }
    fclose(f1);
}

//write matrix
void escribirMatriz(char * nomFichero, Matriz_t * m1, int traspuesta)
{
    FILE* f1 = NULL;
    int i, j;


    f1 = fopen(nomFichero, "w");
    fwrite(&(m1->numFilas), sizeof(int), 1, f1); 
    fwrite(&(m1->numColumnas), sizeof(int), 1, f1);
    if (traspuesta) {
        for (i = 0; i < m1->numFilas; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < m1->numColumnas; j++)
                fwrite(&(m1->datos[j][i]), sizeof(float), 1, f1);
    }
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < m1->numFilas; i++)
            fwrite(m1->datos[i], sizeof(float), m1->numColumnas, f1);
    }
    fclose(f1);
}
//main
int main()
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
        Matriz_t *m1, *m2, *mres;

        m1 = crearMatriz(4, 4);
        m2 = crearMatriz(4, 4);
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                m1->datos[i][j] = j;
                m2->datos[i][j] = i;
            }
        printf("\n Matriz 1: \n");
        printf("%d y %d ", m1->numFilas, m1->numColumnas);
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            printf("\n");
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                printf("%f ", m1->datos[i][j]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n Matriz 2: \n");
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            printf("\n");
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                printf("%f ", m2->datos[i][j]);
            }
        }

        escribirMatriz("matriz3.bin", &m1, 1);
        escribirMatriz("matriz4.bin", &m2, 1);

        //leer matriz
        leerMatriz("matriz3.bin", &m1, 0);
        leerMatriz("matriz4.bin", &m2, 0);
```

Changing the last number "traspuesta" (turn cols and rows) to all 1 1 may work but as the number of cols and rows are not correct, it cannot multiply (And that method is correct, but anyways, it should be alright to have 0's in everything).

Then I do a simple `if` to check if I can multiply those matrixes (M1 `nxm` and M2 `ixj`, can be multiplied `if m==i`, but as the writing method is not working, it never multiplies.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  We have no idea if `m1` is valid, or how `m1->data` was created and whether it is valid or not.  In addition, you don't check if the file was opened successfully.

Comment: Could you please give the definition of `Matrix_t`? I can mostly guess it from your code, but it would be useful to see the exact definition you're using. If at all possible, please also provide a small test matrix demonstrating the problem, preferably combined with your code into a small self-contained test program as suggested by PaulMcKenzie.

Comment: (In particular, check if the `nrows` and `ncols` members in the `Matrix_t` struct really are `int`s. If not, you should fix either the struct or the code to match the actual types.)

Comment: For one, you must open the file in "wb" and "rb" modes, not "w" and "r".

Comment: The matrix definition is on the question now. 
@IlmariKaronen
I'd also add that the crash comes when trying to "`fwrite(m1->data[j][i])`", because the nrows and ncols values are numbers that should not be (really high or negative, I do not know where do they come from, probably "junk".

Comment: @M.K -- That definition only leads to more questions.  Again, we have no idea how, when, or where that `float**` is initialized or populated with values.

Comment: Are you sure `data[j][i]` is correct?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Those data are initialized in the main in a double loop, with 1's and 0s, to help with the future multiplication. ` for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    m1->data[i][j] = j;
    m2->data[i][j] = i;
   }`
Again, add that at the moment, it is a 4 because I am trying to do it with a matrix of 4 rows 4 cols (only at the moment). 
And those m1 and m2 are created in another method with a malloc per rows and a loop malloc per cols. It works alright that part.

Comment: It does not really matter if it is filled up with 1's, 0's or everything with 1's. It is only a way to fill the matrix up. The problem is not in here (I am 90% sure). @n.m.

Comment: So you have incoming junk data, and you show a relatively innocent (the `[j][i]` thing is suspect) function that crashes when fed junk data. Do you want us to tell you why the data is junk? How should we know? The function you have shown doesn't produce it

Comment: In the question, the Fwrite part, instead of taking 4 and 4 for the nrows and ncols, it takes a really big or negative number, maybe because of the &, but I cannot solve why. @n.m.

Comment: @M.K *instead of taking 4 and 4 for the nrows and ncols, it takes a really big or negative number,* -- meaning the issue is not this function, it is what you're doing before this function is called.  Secondly, a `float**` is not a matrix.  It was dynamically allocated somewhere -- we have no idea if this was even done correctly.  Advice -- you shouldn't post just a function that on its surface, *has no issues*.  There is nothing wrong with the `for` loop, assignment statements, etc. **if** the data and all of those variables are correct.

Comment: `&` is correct here. You have to post a [mcve]. There is no way to approach the problem otherwise.

Comment: Is it alright if I make another question with the other methods to show it? @n.m.

Comment: Why? What's wrong with editing this question?

Comment: In previous posts I have been told to re-do another question AGAIN. But it is better to edit the question. Thanks and on my way. @n.m.

Comment: Normally you are asked to ask a different question if you really *have* a different question (i.e. the question you want answered has changed significantly after an exchange of comments). This is not the case here. You still have the same question, you only need to add more source code to it.

Comment: Thank you so much in advance for all the help (you and Paul and Ilmari, for helping so much) @n.m. The question has been edited. I have added everything that I though could be important to what is crashing.

Comment: Please post ONE piece of code that can be copied, pasted, compiled and executed. Do not forget main() and #include directives. Remove code that is not necessary to reproduce the error.

Comment: Should work @n.m. (I had a header and other source file for the methods, but I wrote everything in one for this example.

Comment: Enable your compiler warnings **AND DON'T IGNORE THEM**. You could have solved this in 30 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
escribirMatriz("matriz3.bin", &m1, 1);
```

This is incorrect and any compiler made in this millennium should have at lest warned you about it.

```
mtrx.c:102:39: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘escribirMatriz’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         escribirMatriz("matriz3.bin", &m1, 1);
                                       ^
mtrx.c:53:6: note: expected ‘Matriz_t * {aka struct Matriz_t *}’ but argument is of type ‘Matriz_t ** {aka struct Matriz_t **}’
 void escribirMatriz(char * nomFichero, Matriz_t * m1, int traspuesta)
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
mtrx.c:103:39: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘escribirMatriz’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         escribirMatriz("matriz4.bin", &m2, 1);
                                       ^
mtrx.c:53:6: note: expected ‘Matriz_t * {aka struct Matriz_t *}’ but argument is of type ‘Matriz_t ** {aka struct Matriz_t **}’
 void escribirMatriz(char * nomFichero, Matriz_t * m1, int traspuesta)
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```